# Error:500 unexpected Condition at Xpage application

Tags: xpages

Currently working at 9.0.1 FP6.
 When I Make some changes and run Xpage application at lotus notes it gives me Error 500 : unexpected error condition. To resolve it I sign the application from IBM domino administrator and clean it from designer then I  again execute the application it works fine until I make some other changes .
please some one guide me how to resolve this issue permanently.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do you have the xpage error page checked?

In Designer >> Application Properties >>Errors and Timeouts >> [Check] Display XPage runtime error page.

Checking that option *may* give you some more information - Also, is anything extra written to the server log?

Are you making changes to the design of the application or to a document within the database?

If it is with designer, are you building the project? You should do this really after each change before using the application.

Where you say you sign the database from the admin client, are you doing so with an admin id which is different to the id you are normally using, as if it is a different id, it may be the id you are using does not have the correct rights?

Also, is the database is located in a folder within the Notes data directory? If so try putting the database in the Notes data directory and not in any
subdirectories.

Comment: Dear Chris , thanks for your response. I have already checked this option of display Xpage runtime error page. When I make changes in the design of application this error appear while runing application at lotus notes. I am using a admin client to sign the database and also I am using the same admin user for make design changes at designer. So this user has full rights .Database is located in notes data directory not in subdirectories.

Comment: Like a few of us have mentioned, take a look at the server log, it should give you more information - Post it here if you can't decipher what its telling you

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of quick things:

1. Your code MUST be signed with the same ID. Just re-check by looking at the design elements in Domino Designer!
2. What does the logs on the server tell you? You could use the [Log File Reader project](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Log%20File%20Reader) on OpenNTF to get easy access to these logs and stack traces.

/John

Answer (score 0):

Open the *Domino\data\domino\workspace\logs\error-log-0.xml* file. It contains full stack trace of the error.